# Type 'CKApplicationPermissions' has no member 'PermissionUserDiscoverability'

Tags: permissions, cloudkit

I'm using the cloud kit `fetchUserRecordID` function but need to first authorise access by `requestApplicationPermission` using the following code:

```
func authoriseICloud(){
    container.requestApplicationPermission(.PermissionUserDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
        guard error == nil else { return }

        if status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.Granted {
            // yay!
        }
    }
        }
```

However I'm getting the following error, `Type 'CKApplicationPermissions' has no member 'PermissionsUserDiscoverability'.` Does anyone know how to successfully request permission?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code snippet with Swift 3

```
func authoriseICloud(){
    let container = CKContainer.default()
    container.requestApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.userDiscoverability, completionHandler:{ status, error in
        if status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.granted {
            // yay!
        }
    })
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.